# How do I fail a Jenkins pipeline with below a certain PHPUnit code coverage percentage?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, phpunit, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a Jenkins declarative pipeline to implement continuous integration with my code. The code is a PHP project that uses PHPUnit for unit testing.

Currently, the pipeline

1. builds the project
2. runs a code sniffer to find coding violations
3. runs PHPUnit tests, generating coverage reports and publishing them

If any PHPUnit test fails, the Jenkins job fails (which is good).

Now, I also want to fail the job if the code coverage percentage is below a certain amount. I can't find how to do so.

The current Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    cd symfony && composer install --prefer-dist
                    ./vendor/bin/pcov clobber
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('PHP CodeSniffer') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh './symfony/vendor/bin/phpcs-meq.sh ./symfony/src/AppBundle'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('PHPUnit Tests') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh '''
                        cd symfony
                        cp phpunit.xml.dist phpunit.xml
                        ./bin/console cache:warmup --env=test
                        ./vendor/bin/phpunit\
                            --coverage-clover '../reports/coverage/coverage.xml'\
                            --coverage-html '../reports/coverage'\
                            --log-junit '../reports/unitreport.xml'
                    '''
                }

                junit 'reports/unitreport.xml'

                publishHTML([
                    allowMissing: true,
                    alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                    keepAll: true,
                    reportDir: 'reports/coverage',
                    reportFiles: 'index.html',
                    reportName: 'PHPUnit Test Coverage Report'
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have found this snippet, which publishes the clover report. I thought that perhaps making the "failingTarget" high enough would exit 1 (fail the pipeline) if the coverage didn't make the requirement. It doesn't -- it outputs a warning, but the step still succeeds.

```
            step([
                $class:'CloverPublisher',
                cloverReportDir: '../reports/coverage',
                cloverReportFileName: 'coverage.xml',
                healthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 90, conditionalCoverage: 90, statementCoverage: 90],
                unhealthyTarget: [methodCoverage: 89, conditionalCoverage: 89, statementCoverage: 89],
                failingTarget: [methodCoverage: 88, conditionalCoverage: 88, statementCoverage: 88]
            ])
```

How can I fail a Jenkins pipeline if my PHP code coverage is below a certain threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is xml the only file format available to output the coverage report in?

I would focus on reading the file and then evaluating the necessary elements to determine whether you want to throw an error.

for XML, that would involve importing groovy.util.XmlSlurper, reading the file, parsing it and then navigating the structure.

JSON would be easier, could just use readJSON jenkins basic step and then access the map.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I did something similar. In my repo, I included a python script that parses the XML coverage report and exits with 0 or 1 based on whether it hits a target coverage %. Jenkins runs the script in a stage.